Issue with GitHub Actions Workflow Restarting on Branch Push
I'm encountering an issue with my GitHub Actions workflow, and I could use some help. Here is the relevant part of my workflow configuration:
steps:
  - name:  Get latest code
    uses: actions/checkout@v3
  - name:  Deploy to Stage
    uses: nogsantos/ssh-scp-deploy@v1.3.0
    with:
      src: ./*
      host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
      remote: ${{ secrets.SSH_STAGE_DIR }}
      port: ${{ secrets.SSH_PORT }}
      user: ${{ secrets.SSH_ROOT_USER }}
      key: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY_PRIVATE }}

What I tried:
I set up the workflow to checkout the latest code and deploy it to a staging server using ssh-scp-deploy. The configuration seems correct, and the secrets are properly configured in the repository settings.
What I expected to happen:
I expected the workflow to run once when changes are pushed to the branch, deploy the latest code to the staging server, and then complete without restarting.
What actually happened:
Whenever I push changes to the branch, the workflow starts from the beginning again, resulting in an endless loop of checkouts and deployments.
Has anyone experienced a similar issue or can provide guidance on how to fix this? Any suggestions on what might be causing the workflow to restart and how to prevent it would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Be very careful to configure correctly what happens in the "on" events. for example:
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - dev
  

  push:       
    branches:
      - dev
   

also confirm that you don't commit anything during the workflow. and you can log what is triggering the workflow again:
- name: Print event trigger
  run: echo "${{ toJSON(github.event) }}"

